# How to add receiver name in mailx command

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

My sample data File is

```
$ cat /fullpath/a.csv
a@gmail.com, Amit Singh
k@gmail.com, Km Singh
```

I am using script.sh

```
   #!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do

email=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1 }')
name=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $2 }')

echo | mailx -v -s "Helo $name" -S smtp-use-starttls -S ssl-verify=ignore -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp=smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587 -S from="xxxx@gmail.com(John Smith)" -S smtp-auth-user=xxxx@gmail.com -S  smtp-auth-password=xxxxpassword## -S ssl-verify=ignore -S nss-config-dir=~/.certs "$name<$email>" 

done < /fullpath/a.csv
```

When I send an email, it goes well. but won't pick receiver name in `"$name<$email>"`

how is the correct syntax of receiver name there?

Comment: when i try to edit with full error it show "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: last few lines of error > 250 2.1.0 OK g25sm13460353otr.8 - gsmtp
>>> RCPT TO:<Amit>
553 5.1.3 The recipient address <Amit> is not a valid RFC-5321 address. g25sm13460353otr.8 - gsmtp
smtp-server: 553 5.1.3 The recipient address <Amit> is not a valid RFC-5321 address. g25sm13460353otr.8 - gsmtp
"/home/whoisdat/dead.letter" 28/863
. . . message not sent.

Comment: Your example doesn't contain Amit anywhere so it's hard for us to connect the dots. It certainly looks like your question is also not reproducible with the details you provided, which is another common reason for posts to get closed.

Comment: You'll want to add enough text to explain the code you add to balance things up. In the worst case, you can store a lengthy error message on an external site like pastebin.com and explain that your low reputation prevents you from providing it within the question itself.

Comment: But update the original, not this duplicate.

Comment: Also, probably spend more time in the [help] to understand how this site works, how regular users like yourself have the same mandate as high-rep users like Ed and myself to help moderate this site, how closing as a duplicate was exactly the right course of action here, and how to properly seek corrections if you genuinely thought a mistake had been made. (Hint: ad hominem attacks are not it.)

Answer (score 1):

The correct format would have a space between the real name and the email terminus; but I don't think `mailx` will accept this on the command line, or at the very least not expose it in the `To:` header. Try this instead:

```
echo "To: $name <$email>" |
mailx ... options ... "$email"
```

You are using `IFS` anyway, so why not use it fully?

```
while IFS=, read -r email name; do ...
```

Perhaps a better design still would be to not use a comma as separator.

Comment: it show To: contains invalid character ':'

Comment: when i remove : it show >>> RCPT TO:<Amit>
553 5.1.3 The recipient address <Amit> is not a valid RFC-5321 address. r17sm13058697otq.70 - gsmtp

Comment: Then `$email` somehow ended up not containing the actual email address. Your example doesn't contain "Amit" but I guess you have an entry like `Amit, amit@gmail.com` with the fields in the wrong order; or you somehow got the variables mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

You have commented out the part of the command containing the receiver name, using '##':

```
-S  smtp-auth-password=xxxxpassword##
```

If you need to have your password ending in `#`, put the argument in quotes.

Also, I would put a space after the personal name, i.e. `$name <$email>`. I am not sure whether this is required or just commonly done this way.

Aside from this, I suggest that while testing your script, you run it with `set -x` turned on, so that you see exactly what will be passed to mailx. This will also catch cases where `$email` is incorrect.

Comment: ## was i just type as part of password